# "After Market" Use of Interface Builder in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have an application, **not** built using Interface Builder, and I need to add a new pop-up view to have the user make one of three choices: attack, defend, or go back to the previous screen.  I thought that I would try using Interface Builder to create the view, build the relevant methods, and easily link them together, but I was **sadly** mistaken.

I've seen all of the gripes on this site about working with Interface Builder, but I was hoping that I was making some simple mistake that nobody had bothered to report yet since they had found the result on their own.

This is the XML for the view generated by Information Builder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="5056" systemVersion="13E28" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment defaultVersion="1536" identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3733"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="568" height="320"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="dCs-dd-YuE">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="165" width="568" height="54"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="MarkerFelt-Wide" family="Marker Felt" pointSize="32"/>
                    <size key="titleShadowOffset" width="1" height="0.0"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="Paint My Opponent">
                        <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </state>
                    <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                        <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="boolean" keyPath="btnAttack" value="YES"/>
                    </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                </button>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="BBO-8w-J5r">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="70" width="568" height="54"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="MarkerFelt-Wide" family="Marker Felt" pointSize="32"/>
                    <size key="titleShadowOffset" width="1" height="0.0"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="Defend My School">
                        <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </state>
                    <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                        <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="boolean" keyPath="btnDefend" value="YES"/>
                    </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                </button>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="huu-90-yBz">
                    <rect key="frame" x="513" y="270" width="35" height="30"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="MarkerFelt-Wide" family="Marker Felt" pointSize="15"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="Back">
                        <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </state>
                    <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                        <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="boolean" keyPath="btnBack" value="YES"/>
                    </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                </button>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
            <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <simulatedOrientationMetrics key="simulatedOrientationMetrics" orientation="landscapeRight"/>
            <simulatedScreenMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics" type="retina4"/>
            <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
                <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="keyPath" value="AttackOrDefendViewController"/>
            </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

This is the header file that I created for the "AttackOrDefendViewController" class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface AttackOrDefendViewController : UIViewController

{


}



//  the player has chosen to attack...
- ( IBAction ) btnAttack: ( id ) sender;

//  the player has chosen to defend...
- ( IBAction ) btnDefend: ( id ) sender;

//  go back to the previous screen...
- ( IBAction ) btnBack  : ( id ) sender;


@end  //  end @interface AttackOrDefendViewController
```

This is the implementation of the class:

```
#import "AttackOrDefendViewController.h"

@implementation AttackOrDefendViewController


//  additional setup while loading the view from the nib ("xib" file)...
- ( id ) initWithNibName: ( NSString * ) nibNameOrNil
                  bundle: ( NSBundle * ) nibBundleOrNil

{

    //  always call the parent method...
    self = [ super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil
                            bundle: nibBundleOrNil
           ];

    //  idiot check...
    NSAssert( ( self )
             , @"error allocating object"
             );

    return self;

}  //  end AttackOrDefendViewController::initWithNibName


//  additional setup after loading the view from the nib ("xib" file)...
- ( void ) viewDidLoad

{

    //  always call the parent method...
    [ super viewDidLoad ];

    return;

}  //  end AttackOrDefendViewController::viewDidLoad


//  clean-up method...
- ( void ) dealloc

{

    //  remember to call the parent "dealloc" method...
    [ super dealloc ];

    return;

}  //  end AttackOrDefendViewController::dealloc


//  the player has chosen to attack...
- ( IBAction ) btnAttack: ( id ) sender

{

    return;

}  //  end AttackOrDefendViewController::btnAttack


//  the player has chosen to defend...
- ( IBAction ) btnDefend: ( id ) sender

{

    return;

}  //  end AttackOrDefendViewController::btnDefend


//  go back to the previous screen...
- ( IBAction ) btnBack  : ( id ) sender

{

    return;

}  //  end AttackOrDefendViewController::btnBack


@end  //  end @implementation AttackOrDefendViewController
```

The problem that I'm running into is that, according to everything that I've read here on StackOverflow, there should be a simple method of drag-connecting the objects in the view to the appropriate methods, but nothing is showing up when I Control-Click on the indicated radio buttons, specifically "Touch Up Inside" for the buttons.  I've tried linking the "File's Owner" option to the class as well, but again nothing shows up.

Comment: Control-drag from your `UIButton` to your .m file and an IBAction will be automatically be created for you

Comment: @spassas I've tried that, thanks, but absolutely no effect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  XCode doesn't really behave well when you want to use Interface Builder in an application that wasn't initially built using it.  I needed to manually edit the "xib" file to provide the linkage between the view object and the code, using the "customClass" field in the "placeholder" tag.

```
<placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="AttackOrDefendViewController">
```

After I did that, I was able to link the appropriate buttons with their corresponding methods.

The new "xib" file now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="5056" systemVersion="13E28" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment defaultVersion="1536" identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="3733"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner" customClass="AttackOrDefendViewController">
            <connections>
                <outlet property="btnAttack" destination="dCs-dd-YuE" id="SWe-vI-ryH"/>
                <outlet property="btnBack" destination="huu-90-yBz" id="Pca-Y8-pLI"/>
                <outlet property="btnDefend" destination="BBO-8w-J5r" id="1IN-ev-lSD"/>
                <outlet property="view" destination="iN0-l3-epB" id="cVd-3t-nU0"/>
            </connections>
        </placeholder>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="568" height="320"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="dCs-dd-YuE">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="165" width="568" height="54"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="MarkerFelt-Wide" family="Marker Felt" pointSize="32"/>
                    <size key="titleShadowOffset" width="1" height="0.0"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="Paint My Opponent">
                        <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </state>
                    <connections>
                        <action selector="btnAttack:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="TnY-5r-xlK"/>
                    </connections>
                </button>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="BBO-8w-J5r">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="70" width="568" height="54"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="MarkerFelt-Wide" family="Marker Felt" pointSize="32"/>
                    <size key="titleShadowOffset" width="1" height="0.0"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="Defend My School">
                        <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </state>
                    <connections>
                        <action selector="btnDefend:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="vgx-KL-FM0"/>
                    </connections>
                </button>
                <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="huu-90-yBz">
                    <rect key="frame" x="513" y="270" width="35" height="30"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="MarkerFelt-Wide" family="Marker Felt" pointSize="15"/>
                    <state key="normal" title="Back">
                        <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </state>
                    <connections>
                        <action selector="btnBack:" destination="-1" eventType="touchUpInside" id="fl1-IY-UXH"/>
                    </connections>
                </button>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
            <simulatedStatusBarMetrics key="simulatedStatusBarMetrics"/>
            <simulatedOrientationMetrics key="simulatedOrientationMetrics" orientation="landscapeRight"/>
            <simulatedScreenMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics" type="retina4"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

The new ".h" file now looks like this:

```
//
//  AttackOrDefendViewController.h
//


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface AttackOrDefendViewController : UIViewController

{


}


@property ( retain, nonatomic ) IBOutlet UIView   * viewMain;

@property ( retain, nonatomic ) IBOutlet UIButton * btnAttack;
@property ( retain, nonatomic ) IBOutlet UIButton * btnDefend;
@property ( retain, nonatomic ) IBOutlet UIButton * btnBack;


//  create the view/dialog and move to the main menu screen when completed...
+ ( void ) PromptForAttackOrDefend;


//  the player has chosen to attack...
- ( IBAction ) btnAttack: ( id ) sender;

//  the player has chosen to defend...
- ( IBAction ) btnDefend: ( id ) sender;

//  go back to the previous screen...
- ( IBAction ) btnBack  : ( id ) sender;


@end  //  end @interface AttackOrDefendViewController
```

Thanks.